# Replace string in a file from bash script value

Tags: bash, perl, variable

This bash script runs on a Mac terminal, it needs to ask the user for input `$name`, then replace a string in another file to include the user input `PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME=$name`.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r name

if ! grep -q PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME="\"$name\"" ~/path-to-file.sh; then
perl -pi -e 's/PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME.*/PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME=$name/g' ~/psth-to-file.sh
fi
```

The perl replace command fail to take in the value in the `$name` variable. I am not familiar with Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are not expanded within single-quotes. The `$name` variable is within single-quotes.
You can fix that by breaking out of the single-quotes in the middle:

```
perl -pi -e 's/PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME.*/PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME='"$name"'/g' ~/psth-to-file.sh
```

Notice that I double quoted the variable, to protect from globbing and word splitting.

Comment: Just beware if $name can contain spaces or tabs or newlines...

Comment: Jeff, as I double quoted the variable, I don't see what you mean

Comment: You did -- my mistake!

Answer (score 3):

bash doesn't expand the variable content inside a single quote string. You have to use double quoted strings.

Examples :

This will print : **my name is : $name**

```
name="haha"
echo 'my name is : $name'
```

This will print : **my name is : haha**

```
name="haha"
echo "my name is : $name"
```

So just replace

```
perl -pi -e 's/PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME.*/PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME=$name/g' ~/psth-to-file.sh
```

with

```
perl -pi -e "s/PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME.*/PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME=$name/g" ~/psth-to-file.sh
```